# How to delete row after create 10 minutes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DELETE FROM Login 
WHERE id < DATEADD(hh, -1, GETDATE())
```

I try to run this query, but it's not working. I am using this query in a password reset link functionality, and it should be valid for only 2 hours...

Comment: You are comparing an ID with a date?  That isn't going to work.

Comment: What database is it?

Comment: @SteveWellens unless the `id` is a Date, which would be terrible :)

Comment: @mikeyq6 That would indicate far, far worse problems!

Comment: 10 minutes, 1 hour or 2 hours?

Comment: What you want to do in principle is possible, but you need to put some more effort into your question - give the guys something to work with. As a start, your table should have a createddate, something that tells us when the login was created. Now if you can give us that, then we can solve your problem - pronto ;->

Comment: thank you it's working, compare with datetime